# How can I integrate and manage SMS from many phones?

Tags: sms

I'm looking for a way to integrate SMS messages from my two phones and manage them online using a web site.

I mean that I will be able to send and receive SMS by web, and search my SMS by text.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Voice](http://google.com/voice).

Comment: Indeed. I _lurve_ Google Voice.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to login. I receive alert: Google Voice is not available in your country. I read that this site is available only the USA.

Answer (score 0):

[DeskSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms) is another option, recently released by Koush (maker of ROM Manager).  I haven't tried it myself but it's getting great reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Only answering the "search my sms by text" part, but you can quite easily sync the reseived SMS text messages from both phones to the same (or separate) labels in GMail and then easily search both phone's worth of texts in GMail (on the web, or even in the phones' GMail apps) using an app like [SMS Backup+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync).

SMS Backup+ syncs all of the SMS (and optionally MMS) texts received by a phone to GMail, putting them all in a specific GMail label. If you install it on both phones, you can either sync them both to the same label  if you want them all pooled together, or sync to two similar labels to keep them separate and then you can still search both phones worth of texts in one go.

If you sync them all to the same label, just select that label in GMail and search as normal. If you sync them to separate labels then, if your first phone's messages sync to a label called "smsone" and your second to a "smstwo" label, you can search for the word "test" by putting this in the GMail search box:

```
l:smsone OR l:smstwo test
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [smslemon.com](http://smslemon.com). It is very helpful service. You can send, receive, browse and search your sms. Their Android app can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smslemon&hl=en).